# Cannot get the enemies to chase player pygame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, sprite, game-physics

So I have these enemies that are supposed to swan the player like in the old arcade game RoboTron.

The problem is, only a couple of the enemies go for the player, while the others kind of just stand around, and maybe or more of them will come after the player.  What is going on here?

Here is the code involved in moving the enemies:

```
class Beetle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    '''class that builds up the player class'''

    x_speed = 0
    y_speed = 0

#Beetle construction stuff (images, goes here)

.
.
.



    def speedChange(self,x,y):
        self.x_speed += x
        self.y_speed += y

    def move_towards_player(self, player):

        #contains the beetle to the screen
        self.rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)

        # find normalized direction vector (dx, dy) between enemy and player
        dx, dy = self.rect.x - player.rect.x, self.rect.y - player.rect.y
        dist = math.hypot(dx, dy)
        if dist == 0: #prevents a divide by zero erro
            dist = 1
        else:

            dx, dy = dx / dist, dy / dist
        # move along this normalized vector towards the player at current speed
        self.rect.x += dx * self.x_speed
        self.rect.y += dy * self.y_speed

while done == False:
   while beetleCount < 10:
        beetle = Beetle() #make a beetle
        random1 = randint(0, width -1 ) #make random positions for the beetle
        random2 = randint(0, height - 1)

        beetle.rect.x = random1 #make new random nums
        beetle.rect.y = random2

        beetle_list.add(beetle) #add beetle to list
        all_sprites_list.add(beetle)
        beetleCount += 1 #increment count'''

    for bug in beetle_list:
        random1 = randint(-1, 1)
        if random1 != 0:

            random2 = randint(-1, 1)
        else:
            random2 = 0

        bug.speedChange(random1, random2)
        bug.move_towards_player(player)
```

Here is the entire code, for reference:

```
import pygame
import math
from pygame import K_SPACE
from random import randint

#Define some colors
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
magenta = (255,0,255)
darkOrange = (28, 44, 64)

pygame.init()

#beetleCount
beetleCount = 0


#set the width and height of the screen
width = 800
height = 400
size = [width,height]
mainScreen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
#make a rectangle of the screen size.  This is for keeping 
#the moving non-player objects in bounds
screen_rect = pygame.Rect((0,0), (width,height))


#set the window title
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")

#Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

#clock that is used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#list of all the sprites in the game
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

#sounds in the game that are played
gunshot = pygame.mixer.Sound("gunshot.ogg")
beetleDie = pygame.mixer.Sound("orc_die.ogg")
pygame.mixer.music.load("DeadCity.ogg")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

#Functions VVV
def sprite_sheet_load(colorKey, spriteLocX, spriteLocY, spriteSizeX, spriteSizeY, fileName):
        '''purpose: to extract a sprite from a sprite sheet at the choosen location'''
        '''credit to StackOverFlow User hammyThePig for original concept.'''

        sheet = pygame.image.load(fileName).convert()#loads up the sprite sheet.
        sheet.set_colorkey(colorKey) #set the color key

        #grabs the sprite at the given location
        sprite = sheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(spriteLocX, spriteLocY, spriteSizeX, spriteSizeY))

        #returns the sprite to where ever it was called
        return sprite

##Functions! ^^^

#classes VV

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    '''class that builds up the player class'''

    x_speed = 0
    y_speed = 0

    imageIndex = 0

    playerImagesUp = [] #lists for the player images
    playerImagesDown = [] #lists for the player images
    playerImagesLeft = [] #lists for the player images
    playerImagesRight = [] #lists for the player images
    playerDeathImages = [] # ""

    #constructor function
    def __init__(self):#create a self variable to refer to the object

        #call up the pygame sprite constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        #get the first row of the sprite sheet (moving up)
        spriteXLoc = 15
        spriteYLoc = 15
        spriteXSize = 34
        spriteYSize = 47

        for x in range(0,9):
                self.playerImagesUp.append(sprite_sheet_load(white, spriteXLoc, spriteYLoc, spriteXSize, spriteYSize, "mainCharacter.png"))
                spriteXLoc += 64

        #get the second row (moving left)
        spriteXLoc = 15
        spriteYLoc = 78
        spriteXSize = 34
        spriteYSize = 48
        for x in range(0,9):
                self.playerImagesLeft.append(sprite_sheet_load(white, spriteXLoc, spriteYLoc, spriteXSize, spriteYSize, "mainCharacter.png"))
                spriteXLoc += 65

        #get the third row (moving down)
        spriteXLoc = 15
        spriteYLoc = 143
        spriteXSize = 33
        spriteYSize = 49        
        for x in range(0,9):
                self.playerImagesDown.append(sprite_sheet_load(white, spriteXLoc, spriteYLoc, spriteXSize, spriteYSize, "mainCharacter.png"))
                spriteXLoc += 64


        #get the fourth row (moving right)
        spriteXLoc = 15
        spriteYLoc = 207
        spriteXSize = 34
        spriteYSize = 48
        for x in range(0,9):
                self.playerImagesRight.append(sprite_sheet_load(white, spriteXLoc, spriteYLoc, spriteXSize, spriteYSize, "mainCharacter.png"))
                spriteXLoc += 65


        self.image = self.playerImagesDown[0]


        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def speedChange(self,x,y):
        '''adjust the player speed'''
        self.x_speed += x
        self.y_speed += y


    def update(self):
        '''animate and move the player'''
        #move the character according to the speed it's moving
        #self.rect.x += self.x_speed
        #self.rect.y += self.y_speed

        self.rect.move_ip(self.x_speed,self.y_speed)

        if self.y_speed < 0: #if the player is moving up

            self.image = self.playerImagesUp[self.imageIndex]
            self.imageIndex += 1
            if self.imageIndex >= len(self.playerImagesUp):
                self.imageIndex = 0

        if self.y_speed > 0: #if the player is moving down

            self.image = self.playerImagesDown[self.imageIndex]
            self.imageIndex += 1
            if self.imageIndex >= len(self.playerImagesDown):
                self.imageIndex = 0

        if self.x_speed > 0: #if the player is moving right

            self.image = self.playerImagesRight[self.imageIndex]
            self.imageIndex += 1
            if self.imageIndex >= len(self.playerImagesRight):
                self.imageIndex = 0

        if self.x_speed < 0: #if the player is moving left

            self.image = self.playerImagesLeft[self.imageIndex]
            self.imageIndex += 1
            if self.imageIndex >= len(self.playerImagesLeft):
                self.imageIndex = 0

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    '''class the builds up the bullets that the player shoots'''

    #constructor function
    def __init__(self):

        #call up the parent's constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        #set the size of the bullet
        self.image = img = pygame.image.load("bullet.png").convert()

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def move_bullet(self):
        '''function tells the bullet what direction to go into'''
        bulletSpeed=25
        bulletDirection = 'down'

        if self.bulletDirection =='left':#if the player is facing left
            bullet.rect.x -= bulletSpeed #bullet will go in this direction at that speed
        elif self.bulletDirection == 'right': #if the player is facing right
            bullet.rect.x += bulletSpeed
        elif self.bulletDirection == 'down': #if the player is facing down
            bullet.rect.y += bulletSpeed
        elif self.bulletDirection == 'up': #if the player if facing up
            bullet.rect.y -=bulletSpeed


class Beetle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    '''class that builds up the player class'''

    x_speed = 0
    y_speed = 0
    imageIndex = 0
    BeetleImagesDown = [] #lists for the beetle images
    BeetleImagesUp = [] #lists for the beetle images
    BeetleImagesLeft = [] #lists for the beetle images
    BeetleImagesRight = [] #lists for the beetle images

    #constructor function
    def __init__(self): #create a self variable to refer to the object

        #call up the parent's constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)



        spriteXLoc=11
        spriteYLoc=14
        spriteXSize=30
        spriteYSize=30
        for x in range (0,5):
            self.BeetleImagesDown.append(sprite_sheet_load(magenta,spriteXLoc,spriteYLoc,spriteXSize,spriteYSize, "beetle.png"))
            spriteXLoc + 49

        spriteXLoc=12
        spriteYLoc=65
        spriteXSize=28
        spriteYSize=31
        for x in range (0,5):
            self.BeetleImagesUp.append(sprite_sheet_load(magenta,spriteXLoc,spriteYLoc,spriteXSize,spriteYSize,"beetle.png"))
            spriteXLoc + 49

        spriteXLoc=8
        spriteYLoc=120
        spriteXSize=35
        spriteYSize=24
        for x in range (0,5):
            self.BeetleImagesRight.append(sprite_sheet_load(magenta,spriteXLoc,spriteYLoc,spriteXSize,spriteYSize,"beetle.png"))
            spriteXLoc + 49

        spriteXLoc=9
        spriteYLoc=171
        spriteXSize=36
        spriteYSize=22
        for x in range (0,5):
            self.BeetleImagesLeft.append(sprite_sheet_load(magenta,spriteXLoc,spriteYLoc,spriteXSize,spriteYSize,"beetle.png"))
            spriteXLoc + 49


        self.image = self.BeetleImagesUp[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def speedChange(self,x,y):
        self.x_speed += x
        self.y_speed += y

    def update(self):

        #moves the beetle
        self.rect.move_ip(self.x_speed,self.y_speed)

        #contains the beetle to the screen
        self.rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)

        if self.y_speed < 0: #if the beetle is moving up
            self.image = self.BeetleImagesUp[self.imageIndex]
            self.imageIndex += 1
            if self.imageIndex >= len(self.BeetleImagesUp):
                self.imageIndex = 0

        if self.y_speed > 0: #if the beetle  is moving down

            self.image = self.BeetleImagesDown[self.imageIndex]
            self.imageIndex += 1
            if self.imageIndex >= len(self.BeetleImagesDown):
                self.imageIndex = 0

        if self.x_speed > 0: #if the beetle  is moving right

            self.image = self.BeetleImagesRight[self.imageIndex]
            self.imageIndex += 1
            if self.imageIndex >= len(self.BeetleImagesRight):
                self.imageIndex = 0

        if self.x_speed < 0: #if the beetle  is moving left

            self.image = self.BeetleImagesLeft[self.imageIndex]
            self.imageIndex += 1
            if self.imageIndex >= len(self.BeetleImagesLeft):
                self.imageIndex = 0

    def move_towards_player(self, player):

        #contains the beetle to the screen
        self.rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)

        # find normalized direction vector (dx, dy) between enemy and player
        dx, dy = self.rect.x - player.rect.x, self.rect.y - player.rect.y
        dist = math.hypot(dx, dy)
        if dist == 0: #prevents a divide by zero erro
            dist = 1
        else:

            dx, dy = dx / dist, dy / dist
        # move along this normalized vector towards the player at current speed
        self.rect.x += dx * self.x_speed
        self.rect.y += dy * self.y_speed


##classes ^^

player = Player()

player.rect.x = 350
player.rect.y = 225

#list of all the bullets in the game
bullet_list = []



#default value to what direction the player is facing
faceWhatDirection = 'down'
all_sprites_list.add(player) #add player to list of objects

beetle_list  = pygame.sprite.Group() #list of beetles in the game


# add the beetle list to list of objects
all_sprites_list.add(beetle_list) 




###Main Program Loop

##NOTE: WATCH WHAT YOU ARE PUTTING IN THE LOOPS! EASY WAY TO GET A BUG!
while done == False:
    #Event processing! --------------------------
    for event in pygame.event.get(): #User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #if user clicked close
            done = True #flag that we are done so we exit this loop

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key ==pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.speedChange(-3,0)
                #player.animate()
                faceWhatDirection = 'left'
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.speedChange(3,0)
                #player.animate()
                faceWhatDirection = 'right'
            elif event.key ==pygame.K_UP:
                player.speedChange(0,-3)
                #player.animate()
                faceWhatDirection = 'up'
            elif event.key ==pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.speedChange(0,3)
                #player.animate()
                faceWhatDirection = 'down'
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                gunshot.play()
                bullet = Bullet()
                bullet_list.append(bullet)#adds the bullet to the bullet list
                all_sprites_list.add(bullet)#adds the bullet to the sprite list
                #put the bullet in same location as player
                bullet.rect.x = player.rect.x
                #add in a plus 15 so bullet doesn't spawn in player's face
                bullet.rect.y = player.rect.y + 15 
                bullet.bulletDirection = faceWhatDirection

        #user let up on a key
        elif event.type ==pygame.KEYUP:
            #if it is an arrow key, reset speed back to zero.
            if event.key ==pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.speedChange(3,0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.speedChange(-3,0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.speedChange(0,3)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.speedChange(0,-3)

    player.update() #moves the player around


    #event processing ------------^^

    #Game handling! -------------VV
    ##beetle moving code --------------------------

    #make some beetles
    while beetleCount < 10:
        beetle = Beetle() #make a beetle
        random1 = randint(0, width -1 ) #make random positions for the beetle
        random2 = randint(0, height - 1)

        beetle.rect.x = random1 #make new random nums
        beetle.rect.y = random2

        beetle_list.add(beetle) #add beetle to list
        all_sprites_list.add(beetle)
        beetleCount += 1 #increment count'''

    for bug in beetle_list:
        random1 = randint(-1, 1)
        if random1 != 0:

            random2 = randint(-1, 1)
        else:
            random2 = 0

        bug.speedChange(random1, random2)
        bug.move_towards_player(player)



    #moves the bullets
    for bullet in bullet_list:
        bullet.move_bullet()
        #see if the bullet left the screen
        if bullet.rect.y > 400 or bullet.rect.y < 0:
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
        elif bullet.rect.x > 800 or bullet.rect.x < 0:
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
        #see if bullet hit the beetle
        beetle_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet,beetle_list,False)
        for beetle in beetle_hit_list:
        #remove the bullet and beetle if hit 
            #bullet_list.remove(bullet) #delete the bullet
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet) #remove it from the universal list
            all_sprites_list.remove(beetle) #get rid of the bettle from the universal list
            beetle_list.remove(beetle) #get rid of it from the beetle list
            beetleDie.play() #play the beetle death sound


    #Game Handling! -------------^^



    #Drawing code! --------------VVV

    #clear the screen to a set color
    #NOTE, putting any drawing commands above this will erase
    #whatever you are trying to put there
    mainScreen.fill(white)

    #draw the sprites
    all_sprites_list.draw(mainScreen)
    #update screen on the regular
    pygame.display.flip()

    #Drawing code! -----------------^^

    #limit game frames to 20 frames per second
    clock.tick(20)

#quit the program when the loop is ended

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I think you mean `spriteXLoc += 49` there, and not `spriteXLoc + 49`

Comment: Thanks for the catch there.  Always good to have a second set of eyes.

Comment: Np! I wish I could help more!

Answer (score 0):

```
self.rect.x += dx * self.x_speed
self.rect.y += dy * self.y_speed
```

But x_speed and y_speed are randomly -1, 0, or 1, right?  Then it will move in a random direction...  Maybe you meant the value 1 to be more likely than the value -1.

Comment: That was old code when I had the beetles just run about the screen. The problem is, if I assign it a set speed, then it goes in a random direction, rather than going after the player.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, which I eventually resolved by separating obj.speed from obj.direction, and implementing a strategy pattern to let me swap out enemy behaviors as needed.

For example, let `Enemy` class have a series of methods it calls during its `self.update()` call:

```
def update(self):
    self.unique_action()
    self.shot_check() ##do I shoot or pass?
    self.move()
    self.find_rect() ##make sure the object's Rect is where it needs to be
```

So `self.move()` uses a string to determine which direction the object should go and how to apply its speed.

```
def move(self):
    """Calculates the new position for the object. 
    Uses strings to determine which direction to move in, 
    and uses a speed constant to determine how many pixels 
    in a given direction to move. A string representing 
    two directions ('upleft' or 'downright' for example) 
    will cause it to divide the speed constant by 1.4 
    so it does not appear to move faster when traveling diagonally."""
    speedConstant = self.speed
    if len(self.direction) > 5: ##can only happen if direction is diagonal!
        speedConstant /= 1.4  ##close enough to sqrt(2) for me
    if 'up' in self.direction:
        self.y -= speedConstant
    if 'down' in self.direction:
        self.y += speedConstant
    if 'left' in self.direction:
        self.x -= speedConstant
    if 'right' in self.direction:
        self.x += speedConstant
```

In this way the object is moved based on its `self.direction` value. After this it will execute `self.find_rect()` which just sets its Rect to the correct value after changing the object's x and y values.

Then the seeker behavior can be applied in any number of ways -- as a wrapper to an empty `def foo(self): pass` or by using `types.MethodType()` or just left as a controller in the main loop, whatever you like best -- but the idea is, it just updates the `Enemy` object's `self.direction` value.

```
def enemy_rammer(self):
    """Compares its x and y coordinates against the target and moves toward it.
    If the ship is respawning, the target is its own x and y of origin. 
    If the ship is NOT respawning, the ship is of course the target."""
    self.cooldown = 5 #placeholder, keeps it from seeking AND shooting
    selfX, selfY = self.rect.center
    seekX, seekY = self.xy if ship.respawn else ship.rect.center ##makes it 'go home' if the ship is respawning
    newDirection = '' #safe to assign to self.direction - it won't move
    absX = abs(selfX - seekX)
    absY = abs(selfY - seekY)
    if math.hypot(absX, absY) > self.speed:
        if seekY > selfY and absY > self.speed:
            newDirection += 'down'
        elif seekY < selfY:
            newDirection += 'up'
        else:
            pass
        if seekX > selfX and absX > self.speed:
            newDirection += 'right'
        elif seekX < selfX:
            newDirection += 'left'
        else:
            pass
        self.direction = newDirection
```

It's kind of a lot of code and some maths are probably redundant (late night coding will do that, heh) but it basically checks to see that the 'target' (x, y) is further away than its speed will take it, and if it is, which string to set `self.direction` to.

I mean obviously it doesn't have to be a string to determine `self.direction`, it can be whatever system you want -- but I think separating the *direction* from the *movement* is helpful. If nothing else one manages to avoid some repetition in code by ensuring that `obj.move()` has a consistent implementation. And it also avoids that ugly `obj.speed *= -1` that I see a lot in people's code to indicate something is moving in the other direction. Maybe I'm weird but I don't think that's the right value to be altering; when I drive home from work, I'm not driving -35 MPH...